# Khal Drogo's awareness of his injuries

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have just started watching GoT. I came across the end of Season 1 where Khal Drogo defends Khaleesi and get himself slashed by the sickle across his chest.

Now as per common knowledge, Khal Drogo had become the leader by not losing in any fights. But a warrior/soldier who has been in multiple fights will always have wounds or scars from old wounds. However, in case of Khal Drogo, we practically see no sign of any injuries on his body. To add to this, it is seen that many decisions/disputes within the tribe are settled by combat. Judging by Khal's position, he must have even faced many internal fights. Thus, the lack of any scars is a bit unsettling for me. Also, Dothrakis don't use metal armor thus increasing the chances of injuries even in victories.

Keeping apart the the observations that a great warrior such as Khal has never been injured (which is still disturbing in my mind), can it be said that Khal lacked the awareness of injuries? Had he been aware about the problems an open wound can create, he himself would have called medics to get it cleaned and cured.

Comment: “Keeping apart the the observations that a great warrior such as Khal has never been injured” — if that’s not part of your question, then your question might be clearer if you removed the lenghtly discussion of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From "A Game of Thrones - Daenerys VII":

> She knelt before the khal. "My sun-and-stars is wounded." The arakh
>   cut was wide but shallow; **his left nipple was gone, and a flap of
>   bloody flesh and skin dangled from his chest like a wet rag.**
>
> "**Is scratch**, moon of life, from arakh of one bloodrider to Khal Ogo,"
>   Khal Drogo said in the Common Tongue. "I kill him for it, and Ogo
>   too." He turned his head, the bells in his braid ringing softly. "Is
>   Ogo you hear, and Fogo his khalakka, who was khal when I slew him."

And also:

> "Many riders are hurt," Khal Drogo said stubbornly. "Let them be
>   healed first. **This arrow is no more than the bite of a fly, this
>   little cut only a new scar to boast of to my son.**"

And:

> **Khal Drogo waved him away. "I need no man's help," he said, in a voice
>   proud and hard. He stood, unaided, towering over them all.** A fresh
>   wave of blood ran down his breast, from where Ogo's arakh had cut off
>   his nipple. Dany moved quickly to his side. "I am no man," she
>   whispered, "so you may lean on me."

He cannot show weakness, because at that point his position as Khal is in danger. He can be challenged, and perhaps even defeated. It takes quite a while before he agrees to be treated and by that time it is basically too late.

Comment: I am still not sure if Mirri Maz Duur who instead of trying to heal the wound has poisoned him or just made sure the wound festered. You see a similar wound on one of the Unsulied where the slave master cuts off one nipple and I asume he didn't die of it.

Comment: @Thomas Mirri Maz Duur's actions are discussed [in this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7310/31029).